# "cannot find static files"

Tags: python, django, apache

I've been confused by deploying with Apache and wsgi  these days.
here are some files.

/usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/data/www/default/dj/tangle_with_django_project"
    WSGIScriptAlias / "/data/www/default/dj/tangle_with_django_project/tangle_with_django_project/wsgi.py"
    Alias /static/ "data/www/default/dj/tangle_with_django_project/static"
    <Directory /data/www/default/dj/tangle_with_django_project/static>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ServerName django.skywhat.com
</VirtualHost>
```

sorry for writing the word 'tangle' rather than 'tango' at the very start.
:(
and the others.

```
── static
│   ├── css
│   ├── images
│   │   └── rango.jpg
│   └── js
│       ├── jquery-1.11.3.min.js
│       ├── rango-ajax.js
│       └── rango-jquery.js
```

/data/www/default/dj/tangle_with_django_project/tangle_with_django_project/wsgi.py

```
import os
import sys
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",     "tangle_with_django_project.settings")
sys.path.append(r"/data/www/default/dj/tangle_with_django_project")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

That is the url I'm testing.

http://django.skywhat.com/rango
I cannot find a solution by searching google ...

Comment: In the alias, looks like you are missing a leading `/` - before `data`

Comment: sorry, I fixed it now, but it doesn't have any help.

Comment: What are your static files settings in your project?

Comment: I got it, I write two lines.

Comment: STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT='/data/www/default/dj/tangle_with_django_project/static/'  “Internal Server Error” has been solved.

Comment: http://django.skywhat.com/admin  it shows http://django.skywhat.com/static/admin/css/base.css Not found on the chrome console

Comment: python manage.py collectstatic     can not help me.